# Passing array of UDT argument to Oracle Stored Procedure in ODP.NET

Tags: sql-server, oracle, procedure, odp.net

We need to send data to oracle stored procedure that requires `ITEM_DATA` object array. Within that there is a another array as shown below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ITEM_DATA AS OBJECT
(
ITEM_CODE VARCHAR2 (50),
serial array_serial,
notes VARCHAR2 (1000)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_serial AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(20)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_good_array AS VARRAY(500) OF ITEM_DATA;
```

I want  to implement custom data type classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, connect in server explorer using ODP.NET, and navigate to the User Defined Types node, then find your types and then run Custom Class Wizard to generate a class that you can use to pass data into your stored procedure.

Here is a walk through that should assist you:

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:106658667466148:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:4258,,24

If you are concerned about performance, use associative arrays instead and forgo UDTs.

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks for your reply and the link. Is there any way to pass this data through SQL Server linked server.? Actually I need to pass the data from SQL server to Oracle through linked server. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about what linked server is using to call out to Oracle or what data types are supported. You added the ODP.NET tag which is why I saw your question in the first place. Is it using ADO.NET? If so you could still use my solution. If the linked server is using  ODBC to set up the call to Oracle, well ODBC doesn't support UDTs. If linked server can't support it, what you will probably have to do in that case is to create a wrapper stored procedure in Oracle that takes the values using supported data types and then turns around and calls the original SP.